# Minecraft says that "Our Servers are down"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I start the Minecraft Launcher and type in my Email Address and Password, the Launcher says this:

> "Sorry, but our servers are currently down."
>
> Make sure you are online, (Which I am) or your Computer isn't blocking Minecraft.
>
> SurnCertPathBuilderException: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Do you know what is wrong? Is Minecraft down or is it my computer?

I can log into Mojang, but not Minecraft Launcher and http://minecraft.net.

When I try to log into http://minecraft.net the website says this:

> An error prevented your request from being processed. Please try again.

Comment: Have you ever been able to log into Minecraft?

Comment: To determine the problem, we would need to see the Crash Log, or
the Minecraft Servers may infact be down.

Comment: @BunkPlaysGames There's no crash log generated on this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have experienced an error similar to this, it was as a result of server maintenance and the issue was resolved less than 30 minutes later as soon as their servers were back up. You could go to an online minecraft chat room, like the one in planet minecraft for example, and see if anyone else is having the same issue at the same time that your are. If the issue is not a result of mojang's servers being temporarily down I can't troubleshoot that without more information.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a website such as isitdownrightnow.com to check if the site/server itself is down, or whether it's just on your end.

Comment: this is usually a good idea but "isitdownrightnow.com" can only check HTTP/HTTPS. The launcher error states that it might be a port (not HTTP/S port) blocked or the user is offline. Good mention though!

Comment: True, however the OP mentioned he couldn't log into the actual minecraft website as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/201909)

Comment: @MattR No, this certainly not a comment, but a genuine and self contained effort to help the asker. If you think it's unhelpful or wrong, that's what a downvotes are for.